# Apache mod_rewrite - rewrite port to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a Synology DSM set up for home hosting, and I've been trying to play around with it. My current goal is to assign subdomains to specific services, e.g. the DSM Admin panel, SickBeard, etc.

The only problem with this is the way how Synology manages its services. Some of them are simply webhost-based (and put into the /var/services/web/ folder in their own subfolder), and some of them are running on separate ports (e.g. Sickbeard runs on port 8083, while the admin panel runs on port 5000).

The results are want are quite simple: redirect set subdomains (see below) to these ports, WITHOUT displaying the ports.

admin.fonix232.net -> fonix232.net:5000
sb.fonix232.net    -> fonix232.net:8083
home.fonix232.net  -> fonix232.net:8085
etc.

I've set up a simple mod_rewrite rule for the subdomain admin.fonix232.net, in the following way (in httpd-vhost.conf-user):

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
ServerName admin.fonix232.net

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin\.fonix232\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://fonix232.net:5000/$1 [P,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine, except it does not rewrite the port - it stays 5000, but at least on the subdomain.
How could I remove it?

Comment: this line: _it does not rewrite the_port - it stays 5000,_ seems contradictory. A visit to http://admin.fonix232.net would be on port 80, so what do you mean when you say "it stays 5000"?

Comment: I mean that visiting admin.fonix232.net won't stay on port 80 - it drops me into admin.fonix232.net:5000, and redirects every call to that.

It would also be nice to redirect direct port calls (*.fonix232.net:[PORT] where * does not match [target], to [target].fonix232.net) to their respective target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple, I had to use mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http.

Thanks to the way how Synology built its Apache system (three separate services for system/webman, user and webdav), the best solution was to create a new config file and extend the existing by slightly modifying the startup script to import that too (for some mysterious reasons, any kind of manual addition to config files gets erased as soon as someone edits the settings from webman).

So after that, I had to create separate VirtualHosts for the separate services I wanted to redirect, the following way:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName [full subdomain you want to redirect to]
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / [target address and port you want to reach]
    ProxyPassReverse / [target address and port you want to reach]

    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

While most of the tutorials show that ProxyRequests should be Off, for me it never worked that way, only by enabling it.

Now one thing remains, the exact reverse. Meaning, if port X is called from *.domain.tld, no matter which, drop me on the assigned subdomain.domain.tld. Harder nut to crack, but getting there.